# Как отобразить в шаблоне flask/jijna2 данные из датафрейма

Tags: python, pandas, flask, jinja2

На бекэнде flask во views достал по API данные из Google Analytics, сформировал pandas dataframe. И теперь нужно этот датафрейм отобразить на фронтэнде в jijna2.

Answer (score 0):

Может кому-то пригодится. Делается это очень просто - во view передать датафрейм

```
@app.route("/")
def account():
    return render_template('', title='', df=df)
```

, а в шаблоне вывести уже просто `{{ df.to_html() | safe}}`